# Accessing UDID via Javascript in UIWebView - iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, udid

I know there are many similar questions.  But I am specifically looking to see if UDID can be accessed via Javascript within a custom UIWebView.  If so, how can I go about doing that?

Comment: If you control the app, you can execute arbitrary JavaScript in the context of the webview and also add JavaScript functions.

Comment: Right, but how about if you don't control the app?  I'm developing ad units that are served within a certain mobile ad networks.  Just curious to see if I'd be able to access UDID info right off the bat through the javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible as is.